# Only display latest custom taxonomy post

Tags: custom-taxonomy, loop, taxonomy

I have a custom taxonomy set as a "splash" on my front page, I would like to only display the latest one of these taxonomies as a splash, and any older ones to be returned to the loop and displayed as normal.

My code atm below displays the splash fine, but reproduces the splash again in the loop for some reason:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => '1',
    'order_by' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'theme',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array ('text-image', 'just-image', 'just-text')
        )
    )
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
if (have_posts()) :
    while( $query->have_posts() ) :
        $query->the_post();
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should save the ID of the first post in  a variable (e.g $splash_post_id) and in the next loop, use `"post__not_in" => $splash_post_id` , in the `$args` array.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => '1',
    'order_by' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'theme',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array ('text-image', 'just-image', 'just-text')
        )
    )
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
if (have_posts()) :
    while( $query->have_posts() ) :
        $query->the_post();
        $splash_post_id = get_the_ID();
          .......
          .......
    endwhile; 
endif;

$args = array(
     'post__not_in' => array($splash_post_id),
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => '10',
    'order_by' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
if (have_posts()) :
    while( $query->have_posts() ) :
        $query->the_post();

          .......
          .......
    endwhile; 
endif;
```

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Comment: @kallekillen I edited the answer